# How do i solve my Birch Clustering PyPlot Error Problem

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I've made a Birch Clustering Analysis on my data. Afterwards, I tried to use that code below to plot my analysis and than I got this error.
How can I fix it?
Thank you.

```
# create scatter plot for samples from each cluster
for cluster in clusters:
# get row indexes for samples with this cluster
    row_ix = where(yhat == cluster)
# create scatter of these samples
    pyplot.scatter(dfAB1[row_ix, 0], dfAB1[row_ix, 1])
# show the plot
    pyplot.show()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-840a4662002f> in <module>
      4     row_ix = where(yhat == cluster)
      5 # create scatter of these samples
----> 6     pyplot.scatter(dfAB1[row_ix, 0], dfAB1[row_ix, 1])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3025             if is_integer(indexer):
   3026                 indexer = [indexer]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3078             casted_key = self._maybe_cast_indexer(key)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
   3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: '((array([3586, 3591, 3592, ..., 6982, 6983, 6984], dtype=int64),), 0)' is an invalid key
```

Comment: try `df.iloc[row_ix]`, it works with list however so you might have to convert the array to a list

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried it. Unfortunately didn't work. My code is below;                                                                                                      
list1 = yhat.tolist()                                                                                           for cluster in clusters:
    row_ix = where(yhat == cluster)
    pyplot.scatter(list1.iloc[row_ix, 0], list1.iloc[row_ix, 1])
    pyplot.show()                                                                            AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Comment: no iloc is for the df but row_ix must be a list, not an array

Comment: How should use row_ix as a list?

Comment: like I said, convert it from array to list

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I believe the more data use the more accurate results get. However, you are right. I will try to use smaller datas to solve problem and test it how am i able to solve problem, how many rate. By the way, the technology shouldn't restrict us to use our whole data, but it is unfortunately i guess. Thank you.